# Why does using a std::function declared with the parent show me an error when used with a child?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, std-function

This is the declaration of the virtual Sort-function located in an interface, using a std::function.

```
using Comparefunction = std::function<bool(const DataHandling::GridDataStruct &d1, const 
DataHandling::GridDataStruct  &d2)>;

virtual bool Sort(const Comparefunction& fct);
```

This is the function adressed by the std::function:

```
bool operator() (const Types::Order &d1, const Types::Order &d2)const;
```

where Types::Order is a child of GridDataStruct.

The std::function is used while the class containing the operator above is instantiated:

```
 Sort(Tools::OrderComparer(grid, false));
```

->OrderComparer contains operator showed above

-> Sort also has been mentioned at the top.

If there are any questions respectively a lack of clarity, feel free to ask!

Simplified error message:

No suitable user-defined conversion from (Class containing the operator) to (std::function adressing operator)

Comment: Here's a [mcve] for you (normally you should create this yourself): https://godbolt.org/z/PcA5zJ

Comment: So if the compiler allowed what you are trying to do, what would you expect to happen if some other part of the code called your `Comparefunction` with children of `GridDataStruct` that are _not_ of type `Types::Order`? In simpler terms, your code says `Sort` wants a `CarComparer` but you only give it a `PorscheComparer`. The compiler is completely right to be unsatisfied with that - what if somebody uses the `CarComparer` to compare two `Mercedes` instances?

Comment: Well you have a point there. I really haven't thought of it that way yet.

Comment: I don't know whether your approach is wrong, the question contains way too little information to judge that (which is fine, the original question was less broad). But thinking this through further should lead you to some sort of seam or edge case in your design that is illogical. Maybe you can make `Sort` (or the entire interface) a template instead of run-time polymorphism?

Comment: It already is a template, but the Type is used for the declaration of other abstract functions. So I had to pass over to a different approach. Anyway thank you very much, I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This boils down to

```
struct Base { virtual ~Base(); };

struct Derived : Base {};

struct Comparer
{
    bool operator()(const Derived&, const Derived&)
    {
        return true;
    }
};

std::function<bool(const Base&, const Base&)> comp(Comparer{});
```

https://godbolt.org/z/_7Xtfn

`comp` is supposedly able to compare two `Base` instances. But `Comparer` can only compare `Derived` instances, so it cannot be used to initialize `comp`.

Or, to repeat the above comment: The code says "`Sort` wants a `CarComparer`" but you only give it a `PorscheComparer`. The compiler is completely right to be unsatisfied with that - what if somebody uses the `CarComparer` to compare two Mercedes instances?

Maybe a `PorscheComparer` will only ever be used to compare `Porsche` instances. The clean way to express this would be to template `Sort` (or the entire interface) on the concrete car type - possibly eliminating the inheritance hierarchy entirely (replacing it with compile-time polymorphism).

Answer (score 1):

You're presenting an interface that can take two of anything that derives from `DataHandling::GridDataStruct`.

However, the actual implementation can only take two `Types::Order`s, a more specific, more derived class.

I think you have your expectations backwards here.